# Formatting true/false in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am passing a dict that I get from mysql directly into json. Unfortunately, the json fails when trying to parse the boolean with the following error:

> 'Current token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT) not of boolean type

Is the following the preferred way to cast a `TINYINT(1)` to a javascript boolean?

```
if(tm.is_live, 'true', 'false') live_for_preorder,
```

Comment: What will be the possible values in `tm.is_live` field ?

Comment: This does not look like MySQL error. But it is looking as errror from Elastic Search: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10056

Comment: How did you get the dict? What MySQL version? What table structure/query?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the `tm.is_live` field is a TINYINT(1) and the values will be either `0` or `1`. I think json (ES) is excepting 'true'/'false'.

Comment: what is live_for_preorder datatype and size?

Comment: @comphonia `tm.is_live` is a `TINYINT(1)` -- `live_for_preorder` is just the alias.

Comment: @DavidL your existing query should work. You can also convert `If()` to ANSI SQL compliant `CASE..WHEN` (if you change DB later, as `IF()` is MySQL specific only). In case of `CASE..WHEN`, it would look as follows: `CASE tm.is_live WHEN 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS live_for_preorder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert to a MySQL boolean, simply do:

```
select (tm.is_live <> 0) as live_for_preorder,
```

If this is accepted by Javascript, then this would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall MySQL is one of those rare databases that lets you use IF in normal SELECT statements where most dbms would insist on case, IF being reserved for control flow

As such it appears that MySQL is telling you you’re not providing IF with a Boolean when it wants one. Convert your statement to a comparison that returns a Boolean:

```
if(tm.is_live=1, 'true', 'false') live_for_preorder,
```

(If you’re using 1 for true and 0 for false)

To make your db skill set more portable it would be good to get into the habit of using CASE rather than IF in select queries:

```
CASE tm.is_live WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END live_for_preorder,

CASE WHEN tm.is_live = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END live_for_preorder,
```

A case can have any number of WHEN, but you can’t mix the forms, it’s either `CASE variable WHEN comparevalue THEN outputvalue [when when when else] END` Or it’s `CASE WHEN test THEN output [when when when else] END`

Comment: Sql server will allow you to use iif(condition, result if true, result if false) in a select statement but it is very rarely used (at least from what I have read/seen). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That's implemented as a function though, right? And you can't use IIF for control flow? All major dbms I know of insist on CASE for assignment and IF for flow, except MySQL allows either for both (dirty!)